# Name of compatable operating System

Tags: downloads

I am new to Ubuntu I am not sure what to look for if i want to download any programs. What OS should they be designed for   Linux, IOS, Android or what

Comment: Look in the software center for a good start or https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/ and read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Applications Ubuntu apps should be made for ubuntu of course

Answer (score 2):

Before you consider downloading any software take a look in the Software Centre. Most things you should want are already in there and each of these has been tested with Ubuntu. Not only that but because packages can only be placed in the official Ubuntu repositories by trusted members of the community you can be sure its not Malware, something you can't say about downloading for Windows.

If you still can't find what you are looking for it may be available in a third party repository which again has the advantage of being easy to install but since you are not getting your software from an Official Ubuntu source now you have to decide if you trust the publisher as you could be installing Malware.

If you still cant find what you are looking for it may be available as Debian package '*.deb' file. Note however the way Linux works a lot of programs depend on other programs and using the software centre, or repositories takes care of this for you. Once you start using Debian packages directly you need to take of this your self so I wouldn't recommend this to a new user.

Finally it is possible software from the source code but since you are asking such a basic question you are not ready to install from source yet.

Ubuntu is derived from Debian Linux it is not Android or iOS

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is a Debian-based Linux OS. So you should look for a) Linux, b) Ubuntu, c) Debian (.deb-files)

Dependencies might not always be resolved if you download from any webpage, so the very first step should be to check if the program (or a reasonable alternative) is already listed in the repositories. Check the Ubuntu Software Center for that.